# Vertical cut off of text in label with letters such as p and g

Tags: swift, layout

I have a label in a stack view that displays a variety of different text however when it displays p and g, the bottoms are cut off as you can see here.

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this?

Update: I need the size of my label to stay the same and rather the font size of the label to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding

```
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
           OR
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

to your label

## This seems to work only when width is insufficient but not height

Try this. It should do the trick

```
extension UILabel {

override open func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    while self.font.pointSize > 1 {
        //check the contentSize, if it's less then the actual label height then it should fit
        //else change the font size
        if self.intrinsicContentSize.height < self.frame.size.height {
            break
        }
        self.font = self.font.withSize(font.pointSize - 1)
    }
}

}
```

Comment: this does not work for some reason I had tested this out before and it results in the same thing happening

Answer (score 1):

Just play with its compression resistance:

```
 label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
```

The compression resistance is how flexible the view is to compress when screen size shrinks. Setting a higher value means that we don’t want the view to shrink smaller than the intrinsic content size.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your label is always big enough for the content inside, you need to call `sizeToFit()` every time after you set the text.

Here is the sample code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.text = "gpb"
    label.backgroundColor = .red
    label.sizeToFit()

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,
                         selector: #selector(self.timerDidFire(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func timerDidFire(timer: Timer) {
    size += 5
    label.font = label.font.withSize(CGFloat(size))
    label.sizeToFit()
}
```

And it looks like

[image]

Comment: auto shrink is already on so I don't think that those will make a difference

Comment: @joshLor Updated my answer.

Comment: sadly because of my layout that will not work for me (size to fit)

Comment: @joshLor Are you saying that you want the size of your label to stay as it is and just change the font size?